# MOSFET switch, ATtiny10, Raspberry Pi

Tags: mosfet, switches, raspberry-pi, attiny

I had posted a question earlier but I was using a BJT at the time and the solution provided led me to use a MOSFET for my application instead. I switched to the FET but still unable to provide stable Power to my Pi. Is my ATtiny10 pin current too low to drive the Gate of this FET? Is there something wrong with my circuit design? I get at most 120mA to the Pi but my source current is providing 3A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEwzaR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not driving the FET with a high enough voltage. Remember, the threshold voltage \$V_{th}\$ is the voltage at which the FET *just barely begins* to allow current through--not the voltage at which it's fully on. If you look on page 4 of [the datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPSA70R900P7S-DS-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625f2e26bc015f4e4118ec13fb):

[image]

you'll see that the on-state resistance is specified at a \$V_{GS}\$ of 10V, twice what you have. And some of the other specifications are rated at a \$V_{GS}\$ of 13V!

Comment: I had no idea about that spec. I know the site frowns on requesting part suggestions but since I have been trying to get this to work for a while now would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: The trick is to search for "logic-level" FETs. Hopefully that search term helps!

Comment: If the drain-source on-state resistance spec says Vgs=5V and Id=1.1A, does that mean my load can only receive 1.1A at most?

Comment: @SChand That just means that's the current at which it was tested.

Comment: Rds is also important for this application. You don't want to drop more than a few tenths of a volt.

Comment: The ATtiny10 provide 3.2-3.5V at the Gate and the Pi is able to flow 120mA through it. Not sure what the 10V parameter means now since it seems to work to a degree at 3.5V

Comment: @Mattman944 what is the voltage range? I was told 10V but it seems to allow some current at 3V

Comment: @SChand Ten volts is what they consider to be fully on; in saturation rather than linear mode (for reasonable \$V_{DS}\$). Anything above \$V_{th}\$ will conduct at least a little bit. Current is proportional to \$V_{GS} - V_{th}\$, in linear mode.

Comment: @Hearth thanks for that explanation. Ya I will have to reconsider the part then as I can only supply 3V from the MCU and need 3A to flow

Comment: @SChand Only 3V digital out with a 5V supply? That's odd.

Comment: @Hearth 5V supply to ATtiny10 Vcc. The multimeter on Pin0 Digital out said 3.2-3.5V when "ON".

Comment: @Hearth if you happen to click on this by accident... https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PSMN2R0-30PL-1318146.pdf ...
does this meet the specs of what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SChand It looks like it would probably work, though it wouldn't be my first choice--it's a bit overkill! I'd look at [these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1993=61&pv1993=19&pv1993=80&pv1993=81&pv1993=28&pv1993=40&pv1993=88&sf=1&FV=ffe00116&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) parts, which are rated to be driven by no more than 3 volts for the minimum \$R_{DS,on}\$.

Comment: Try something like the AO3400: http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3400.pdf This is a logic level power FET with very low RDS(on). It's worth noting that you would be better using a high side switch so perhaps consider the AO3401.

Comment: @Hearth thanks for the suggestion. It's a little tricky searching for this part since I have 3V to drive the Gate but need continuous current of 3+ Amps

Comment: @JackCreasey thanks! That seems like another viable option. I already ordered the part listed above so will just try that. I am getting some outside feedback that my initial FET should work so have a few experiments to run on that as well